# Manipulating input in Java

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //call for input
    System.out.println("Please Enter a 3-digit number..");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] num = new int[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
        int val = in.nextInt();
        num[i] = val;
    }

    System.out.println("The Sum of the numbers is " + sumNums);
    System.out.println("The Reverse of the numbers is " + reverseNums);

}

public int sumNums(int x) {
    return num[0] + num[1] + num[2];
}

public in reverse(int x) {
    return num[2] + num[1] + num[0];
}
```

I'm trying to create a couple methods that add a broken up number, for example, if I enter 123, it would result in 1+2+3=6, but I keep getting "cannot find symbol". Also is the way I broke up the input the most efficient?

Comment: You need to understand how variables and parameters work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems with your implementation.

In your `println`, you are not making a method call

```
System.out.println("The Sum of the numbers is " + sumNums);
System.out.println("The Reverse of the numbers is " + reverseNums );
```

Should be

```
System.out.println("The Sum of the numbers is " + sumNums(0));
System.out.println("The Reverse of the numbers is " + reverseNums(0) );
```

Also, your current `sumNums` and `reverseNums` methods aren't using the parameter passed in and they could probably be removed...

Comment: non-static method cannot be referenced from a static content is the error I get after making that change?

Comment: That's because `sumNums` and `reverseNums` are not static methods.  Probably the easiest way to resolve that is to define the methods as `public static int`

Answer (score 0):

The `()` at the end of the function call is not optional in java, so in your `println`s, you need to say `sumNums()` instead of `sumNums`. (there is no point of the `int x`, I assume you remove it.

There are other issues.. such as `in` should be `int`, and infact should probably be `String` if you want to reverse the number.. right now all you are doing is adding them up. And you probably want to pass `num` as a parameter to the other functions, or make it a class member..

Answer (score 0):

1. your last method's return type has a typo.
2. you need to define the array num out of the main method(as a field), or the other methods didn't know this variable(Methods : OMG, What's is the num?)
3. calling a method is like that : methodName(params...)
4. I don't think you need to use the par "x" in those methods.
5. I recommend you to try a better code style

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't worry about efficiency if I were you.  Right now, your program isn't getting *any* input into the methods that need it.

Two main things here:

- Your methods aren't `static`, so you can't call them inside of `main()` without an instance of your class (let's call it `TestClass` for the time being).
- You don't pass any of the information you get from the user to your methods to begin with.  This is the reason you're running into "cannot find symbol" - `num` has no definition in the scope of those methods.

To at least remedy the latter issue, you should change the signature of your methods to accept an int array instead of a single int:

```
public int sumNums(int[] num) {
    return num[0] + num[1] + num[2];
}

public int reverse(int[] num) {
    return num[2] + num[1] + num[0];
}
```

I wouldn't expect the results of these two methods to differ in any way though, since addition is commutative.

Instantiating the object, and calling the methods, I leave as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: The reverse method im trying to reverse the order of input. input=123 output=321